Test Kitchen unable to run Inspec tests due to SSH Key Algorithm Error
I'm not familiar with the depths of the Test Kitchen tools as I normally use them for simple cookbook tests and generally don't run into issues.
At the moment, I'm trying to test updates to a cookbook, but when I run "kitchen test" I see that the converge is happening and seems to finish just fine. But when it tries to run the Inspec tests post-converge, I'm getting an error:
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Failed to complete #verify action: [Transport error, can't connect to 'ssh' backend: SSH command failed (host key algorithm mismatch for signature 'rsa-sha2-256' != 'ssh-rsa')] on default-rhel-9
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration

If I try to run "kitchen login" it works just fine, which I would think indicates that the key algorithm used by the kitchen tool is perfectly valid.
I tried just doing:
kitchen create
and then, in another shell,
kitchen login
Once I was logged in, I ran:
sshd -T | grep kex
Which returned the following:
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
After running kitchen converge the same command returned:
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Part of our cookbook removes non-secure algorithms as part of our security compliance. This error has not happened in the past on RHEL6-8, CentOS 7-8, or AmazonLinux2 and 2023. This has just now started happening as I started testing with RHEL9.
I appreciate anything that can help point me in the right direction here.

As it turns out, it appears that there was a line in my sshd_config template that was as follows:
<% if node['platform'] != /amazon/ %>
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
<% end %>

This had not been a problem until I began testing with RHEL9. With RHEL9, I had to include another guard to prevent this line from being inserted into the sshd_config file on RHEL9 systems, so now the block looks like this:
<% if node['platform'] != /amazon/ && node['platform_version'].to_i != 9 %>
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
<% end %>

Moving forward, I suppose I should investigate exactly why I added the original block...this was several years ago, now. It may be necessary to do something like this on RHEL9, but for now, I'm going to leave it like this.
